# Экспорт jQuery плагинов

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу экспортировать плагин на jQuery, который находится в отдельном файле?

Для примера:

```
$.fn.someFunc = () => {
 // тут какой-то код
}
```

export default someFunc; // так не получается

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, import/export работает на node.js вроде...

Comment: Да, мне как раз на React проекте это все и нужно реализовать. Простые функции экспортировать не проблема export default someFunc
А вот как быть с $.fn.someFunc